# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at end of input Position: 684;

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema_vtvs_ai_ext.fire(
      fire_number VARCHAR(50),
      fire_year DATE,
      assessment_datetime INTEGER,
      size_class  CHAR,
      fire_location_latitude REAL,
      fire_location_longitude REAL,
      fire_origin VARCHAR(50),
      general_cause_desc VARCHAR(50),
      activity_class VARCHAR(50),
      true_cause VARCHAR(50),
      fire_start_date DATE,
      det_agent_type VARCHAR(50),
      det_agent VARCHAR(50),
      discovered_date DATE,
      reported_date DATE,
      start_for_fire_date DATE,
      fire_fighting_start_date DATE,
      initial_action_by VARCHAR(50),
      fire_type VARCHAR(50),
      fire_position_on_slope VARCHAR(50),
      weather_conditions_over_fire VARCHAR(50),
      fuel_type VARCHAR(50),
      bh_fs_date DATE,
      uc_fs_date DATE,
      ex_fs_date DATE
    );
```

This is the SQL code i have written to add an external table in Redhsift schema but the below error. i can't seem to see where the error is?

```
    [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at end of input  Position: 684;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in Amazon S3, then you need to specify the file format (via STORED AS) and the path to data files in S3 (via LOCATION).

This is the example query for csv files (with 1 line header):

```
create external table <external_schema>.<table_name> (...)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
stored as textfile
location 's3://mybucket/myfolder/'
table properties ('numRows'='100', 'skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

See [official doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE.html) for details.

Comment: Yes the data is in S3 bucket, i have a doubt here the location you are mentioning is the location of the S3 bucket or do i need to provide the exact location of the file, cause i have 2 csv files in there?

Comment: You can't provide path to the specific file there. I'd suggest to specify the path to the folder in the bucket, where your 2 files are located (like s3://mybucket/myfolder/).Then it will scan all the files in this folder (including subfolders).
Just in case: Redshift ignores hidden files and files that begin with a period or underscore.

Comment: For the query you have mentioned do then i explicitly need to copy the data from my file into the table( using the copy command) or will it be taken care of in this query?

Comment: Also does the stored as clause support CSV file, cause i read somewhere that it does not.

Comment: If you create the external table, data is not copied to the table. You can query and retrieve data from files in Amazon S3 directly.

Comment: Edited my answer - now the example query is for csv files case.